# What is libgtk-x11-2.0.so library?

Tags: libraries

I am trying to migrate my code from gtk2 to gtk3 . So instead of the library libgtk-x11-2.so which library i should use in gtk3. And What is the use of libgtk-x11-2.0.so ? is this library is a gtk2 related library. Which functions are used libgtk-x11-2.0 .

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgtk2.0-0 & my box (`apt-cache show`) tells me *GTK+ is a multi-platform toolkit for creating graphical user interfaces. Offering a complete set of widgets, GTK+ is suitable for 
 projects ranging from small one-off tools to complete application suites.* but your question is too broad & unclear as written so I'm voting to close too.

Comment: Is libgtk2.0-0 and libgtk-x11.2.so are related libraries or not ? if so what is the respective library available in libgtk3.0-0 for the same?

Comment: GTK+2 is much older, and lots of apps still use it.  If only GTK+3 libs were available, then you'd have to expect most GTK+2 programs to segfault if forced to use gtk+3 libs (as API/abi's wouldn't line up correctly).  My own box is 19.04 & the library exists on it, for all I know I've used.  I picked a program `leafpad` and checked, yep it uses it.  No doubt there are lots more I have installed.

Comment: I want to migrate my code from gtk2 to gtk3 . so instead of libgtk-x11-2.so library which library i should use?

Comment: Okay I understand you question better now.  I would suggest clarifying your question including more information as to reason, as you've already got a number of close votes (unclear & too broad) and the extra detail will help your question staying open.   This however may help - https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html

Comment: I did the same things whatever they told in that web page and whenever i compiling am getting error like gtk2.x symbols are present in the application. So that i came to the conclusion that this library is causing the problem. So how should i replace this library in gtk3. And thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer . The gtk-x11-2.0.so is a gtk2 function only. I should use libgtk-3 instead of that . 
If you will type `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` it will show the gtk2 libraries and if you will type `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` it will show gtk3 libraries .